# Unity - Gravity not working when opening from another scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple mini-game in unity as a separate scene. The problem is that the gravity works completely fine on my rigidbody when I start from the mini-game scene, but when I move to the mini-game scene from another the gravity stops working and my player can only go up.

### Here is what I've tried:

- My Project's Physics 2D settings are fine (Gravity: X = 0, Y = -9.81)
- My Project's Time setting is fine (Time Scale: 1)
- My Player character has a Rigidbody2D, which is Dynamic, Simulated (true), Gravity Scale = 5, ONLY rotation is frozen, and it's set to never sleep.
- The Player also has box and circle colliders (both 2D).
- All player inputs are read in Update(), and all physics are done in FixedUpdate() (I am using velocity to move the player).

I do have a GameController object which is carried between the scenes, but none of it's scripts should affect the scene (I can provide the OnLevelWasLoaded() parts of the scripts or any other parts).

Here is the code in my player controller:

```
void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        box = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        _renderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        velVer = 30f;
        velHor = 10f;
    }

void Update()
    {
        moveHor = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        moveVer = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        buttonUp = Input.GetButtonUp("Vertical");
        _moveVector = new Vector2(moveHor, moveVer);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if (IsGrounded() && buttonUp)
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(velHor * _moveVector.x, velVer * _moveVector.y);
        if (_moveVector.x != 0 && _moveVector.y == 0)
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(velHor * _moveVector.x, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        RaycastHit2D raycast = Physics2D.BoxCast(box.bounds.center, box.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, 0.1f, layer);
        return raycast.collider != null;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag.Equals("Heart"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

I have commented out any references to the GameController object from all scripts in the mini-game scene, so the GameController should not have any impact on my mini-game character controller.

I am desperate, I have searched online for more than 3 hours and haven't found anything that could help me (if I did actually miss a solution my apologies).
I can provide any further information you may require.

EDIT:
Here are Gifs of character behaviour when I start the game from the mini-game scene, and when I move to the mini-game scene from another.

Working (started mini-game directly):

[image]

Not Working (moved to mini-game from another scene):

[image]

Comment: Do your object's think they are grounded or do they know they are in air and still won't fall?

Comment: @Jake the objects know when they are in the air but don't fall. When the scene starts the player is positioned on ground so the player can jump up once, but because the character doesn't fall back down IsGrounded() returns false after that and the player is only able to move from left to right, mid air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have found the issue! I thought the problem would lie inside the scripts that are inside of my mini-game scene, or in the scripts carried into the scene by my GameController, but that was not the case. The problem laid in a script attached to an object located in a scene from which I moved to the mini-game.

Here if the troublesome line:

```
Physics2D.gravity = Vector2.zero;
```

Because my game is 2D with Axonometric projection (3/4) I set the gravity to Vector2.zero very early into the development. I have replaced that with simply setting the gravity scale to 0.

```
rb.gravityScale = 0;
```

Even though the script with the troublesome line doesn't move to my mini-game scene it modified the gravity setting of the entire project.
VERY silly mistake, which I probably would find, but after many hours of constant development my brain wasn't functioning too well, and I decided to post this question.

Thanks for the help anyway guys!

Answer (score 0):

Check for three things:
1) Are you sure that you didn't set timeScale to 0 in any other script?
2) Does your player have the same scale on both levels? 
3) Why do you use Physics2D.BoxCast in IsGrounded function? I usually use [Raycast2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray2D.html) for the ground checking process.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering! To answer your points:
1) I do set timeScale to 0 in some parts of the scripts, but these parts are never reached in my testing.
2) I am aware of the scale issue in unity that causes similar problems, but I checked and that's not the issue in my case.
3) I am using BoxCast to ensure the player is considered to be grounded, even if only a pixel of his collider is touching the platform (it's part of a gameplay mechanic I am going for). And to get the same effect with Raycast2D I would have to case multiple rays. I found BoxCast to work better in my case.

Comment: Hey Sebastian. your BoxCollider has the same size on both levels? please check it on Editor after loading your minigame scene.
and Are you using Additive mode?

Comment: Hey @Mohammad Yes the box collider is the same in both levels. I have just found the issue, and its a silly mistake on my part. I posted the answer below. Will close this thread tomorrow when I can accept my own answer. Thanks for the help anyway!