# Scene is going up at start up

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, unity3d-editor, oculusquest

Scene is going up in space when apk is start up or player is going down at start up of scene in VR headset. There is no rigidbody applied on player. Please help
There is no gravity or rigidbody applied to camera/player, scene. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity - Gravity not working when opening from another scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61261916/unity-gravity-not-working-when-opening-from-another-scene)